# How to determine application run under Visual Studio vshost or not?

Tags: c#, if-statement, vshost32

**I have an app build in Release Mode.**
I want when I run app by Visual Studio (F5 key), variable `is_vshost` have have value `true`, and if I rebuild app and open it directly in Windows Explorer, it have value `false`. How I can do that? Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value of

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

It should be `devenv.exe` when running from within VS.

Answer (score 1):

In code, you can check to see if the vshosts.exe is running by looking at the CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.  If it ends in ".vshosts.exe" then it's running.

```
    bool is_vshost = false;
    int i = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.IndexOf(".");
    string s = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Substring(i);
    if (s == ".vshosts.exe")
        is_vshost = true;
```